# GotMouseCapture via XAML

Tags: wpf, button, styles

This is my `button` style:

```
<Style x:Key="NoBorderButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="false" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

i want to add another `Trigger` to my `button`: `GotMouseCapture` and `LostMouseCapture` but i didn't find it, only via code behind:

```
private void btnClose_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btnClose.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}

private void btnClose_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btnClose.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EventTrigger`, here is an example:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotMouseCapture">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                            To="DarkGray"
                            Duration="0:0:0"/>
        </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
 </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: In this way the color stay in DarkGray after lost focus and not changed back to white

Comment: My code was just an example of the `IsFocused` trigger in action. Simply create another `Trigger` for when `IsFocused` is false, and set it's `Foreground` to `White`.

Comment: I already try it but in this way it disabled my other trigger that change my Foreground when IsMouseOver

Comment: XamlParseException: Key cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key